# Objective-c How to make GUI window from terminal app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, user-interface

Is there a way in obj-c to make a gui window, while there is no .app bundle, just extcutable? The problem is that I need a gui application(just one dialog).

I tried:
Import appkit.framework into the terminal app. - crashes with tons of reasons.
I decided that using x11 is not a good idea because it is not included in OS X 10.8

So, any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the reasons to your question

Comment: The usual approach is to symbolically link a "command line app" as a symlink to the executable inside the app bundle.  The Mac OS X launcher/dock wants a bundle.  If you have a problem with it being in a bundle just hide the bundle somewhere people won't see it (like not in /Applications) and voila, what's the difference? Do you really need to make sure people can't double click your thingy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly you need to have a NSApplication running, but you don't need to have an app bundle.

Make sure that when you create your project you select "Foundation" as the type. Then you can set it up like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindow *window;
}
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        // total *main* screen frame size //
        NSRect mainDisplayRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

        // calculate the window rect to be half the display and be centered //
        NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(mainDisplayRect.origin.x + (mainDisplayRect.size.width) * 0.25,
                                     mainDisplayRect.origin.y + (mainDisplayRect.size.height) * 0.25,
                                     mainDisplayRect.size.width * 0.5,
                                     mainDisplayRect.size.height * 0.5);

        /*
         Pick your window style:
         NSBorderlessWindowMask
         NSTitledWindowMask
         NSClosableWindowMask
         NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
         NSResizableWindowMask
         */
        NSUInteger windowStyle = NSTitledWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask;

        // set the window level to be on top of everything else //
        NSInteger windowLevel = NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1;

        // initialize the window and its properties // just examples of properties that can be changed //
        window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:windowStyle backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
        [window setLevel:windowLevel];
        [window setOpaque:YES];
        [window setHasShadow:YES];
        [window setPreferredBackingLocation:NSWindowBackingLocationVideoMemory];
        [window setHidesOnDeactivate:NO];
        [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // make the window visible when the app is about to finish launching //
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    /* do layout and cool stuff here */
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    /* initialize your code stuff here */
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // release your window and other stuff //
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [app setDelegate:[[[MyAppDelegate alloc] init] autorelease]];
        [app run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that the line [app run]; is blocking so you would have to run your logic either within the application loop or on a new thread (application loop preferred).

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Boo.. I was too late!

Comment: Just to expand on @Chris Devereux's answer, after doing this you don't have to setup a run loop because the line [app run]; actually creates a run loop for you. At that point, you can treat your app *almost* as if you had a bundle.

Comment: Aww man, first answer too. Welcome to SO anyway! Often, questions get answered quite quickly, so it can be a good idea to avoid long code samples unless they're really needed (or edit them in later).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing should be possible without creating a .app, however you will need to run the AppKit event loop (otherwise, where would user input events come from?).

The simplest way to do this would be to get the shared NSApplication object and call its run method. You may be able to set up an event loop manually using nsrunloop, however I'm not sure whether the input sources needed are a public API.

Why do you not want a .app? It is likely that whatever you are doing will be easier if you follow the standard patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just make a cocoa application and simply drag and drop the files you need into the new application. Make sure to tick the box "add to target" and "copy items into destination. . ."

I have made many of these little helper applications that does a simple task just to help me out with something else. And this is usually the way I do it.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my issue. The problem is that I can't make any .app bundles. I need everything to be hardcoded into the executable. But NSApplication requieres a bundle. So I am seeking for a way to do it&